# Tiempo de respuesta de una Servidor en flutter

Tags: api, servidor, flutter, dart, https

Mi aplicación se conecta a una api creada por mi en el manejo de errores estoy intentado implementar uno para notificar que el servidor no responde pero la excepción tarda demasiado tiempo tomarla quisiera saber si existe alguna manera para verificar mas rápido si el servidor esta disponible o no

```
var response;
  try {
    response = await http.post("http://192.168.137.6:3000/loggin/", body: {
      "user": usert.text,
      "pass": passt.text,
    });
  } on SocketException {
      throw ('Sin internet  o falla de servidor ');
  } on HttpException {
    throw ("No se encontro esa peticion");
  } on FormatException {
    throw ("Formato erroneo ");
  }
```

Esta seria la manera en como lo verifico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar [`Future.timeout`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.0.0-dev.69.2/dart-async/Future/timeout.html) la cual lanzará una excepción del tipo [`TimeoutException`](https://api.dart.dev/dev/2.0.0-dev.69.2/dart-async/TimeoutException-class.html) una vez alcanzado el tiempo de espera indicado.

#### Ejemplo:

```
  var response;
  try {
    response = await http.post("http://192.168.137.6:3000/loggin/", body: {
      "user": usert.text,
      "pass": passt.text,
    }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));

  } on TimeoutException catch (_) {
     throw ('Tiempo de espera alcanzado');
  } on SocketException {
      throw ('Sin internet  o falla de servidor ');
  } on HttpException {
    throw ("No se encontro esa peticion");
  } on FormatException {
    throw ("Formato erroneo ");
  }
```